# DOMDocument tag is not just for PHP. Generalize it?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the tag for DOMDocument reads:

> domdocument is a class in PHP's DOM API to access and manipulate the DOM

I submitted an edit to at least capitalize DOMDocument and added a period.  Currently it's just awful.

However, my real beef with this tag is that it isn't PHP specific.  It's also used by Xerces, and probably a handful of other DOM/XML parsers.  I feel we should generalize it, as you can use `[php]` `[domdocument]` to reflect the PHP specific version.

This came to my attention when posting [Quickly selecting elements in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060824/quickly-selecting-elements-in-the-dom). I opted simply to use the `[dom]` tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change to the tag wiki, I also need to get it approved though.

The word DOMDocument is used by several languages and technologies to refer to an object covering the DOM.